# Redis queue stores items in list as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, redis, node-redis

I'm using curl to send POST requests to my node.js app. The POST request is then processed and pushed to a Redis queue.
But when I check my redis queue, all the items in the list are displayed as [object Object].
Here is my code,

```
var http = require('http');
var qs = require('querystring');
var redis =  require('redis').createClient();

redis.lpush('XMLqueue','post');

console.log('Server Starting Now: ');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    //res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    //res.end('Hello World\n');

    if(req.method == 'POST'){

        var body="";

        req.on('data', function(data){
            body += data;
        });

        req.on('end',function(){
            var post = qs.parse(body);
            console.log(post);

            //var p = post.toString();
            var p = JSON.encode(post);
            redis.lpush('XMLqueue',p);
        });
    }
});
```

Only 'post' which I push discretely is displayed properly.
Otherwise all items are displayed as 
1)"[object Object]"
2)"[object Object]"
.
.
I use this curl command to pass data,

```
curl --data "What=Hello&world=name" http://127.0.0.1:8124
```

I check the redis queue using another terminal with this command,

```
>lrange XMLqueue 0 -1
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: Try `var p = JSON.stringify(post)` instead of `var p = JSON.encode(post)`. I've had a similar problem in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis only accepts a few input structures.
So we need to convert JSON to a string. So we use

```
var p=JSON.stringify(post)
```